# What is the best way to access Microsoft Exchange Server 2003 on Mac?

Tags: macos, exchange-server

We have an iMac and our server runs a Microsoft Exchange Server 2003. We can setup the Mail.app to retrieve and send mail but how can we access the public contacts and calendar? We bought Mac Office 2011, but that Outlook only seems to support Microsoft Exchange Server 2007. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: After I set up Mail with Exchange Server, I found that iCal is already displaying my corporate events from there, and Address Book searches in global directory, I didn't even have to configure them. Is it what you want?

Comment: Hmm, I just checked iCal and Mail but both did not pick up the events. I gave up so I am going to ask a better question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had this problem. Here is my workaround:

1. install Davmail Gateway from http://davmail.sourceforge.net
2. in OS X mail client set up POP account and use localhost as incoming and SMTP server host. get some hint from this page davmail.sourceforge.net/thunderbirdmailsetup.html
3. you might see error at first time, but continue once you are done with the wizard, go to advanced setting to choose correct port numbers according to the port numbers in Davmail setting pannel.
4. in OS X calendar client, add CalDev address as stated here davmail.sourceforge.net/osxicalsetup.html

tested on two macbook pro laptops, it should work, good luck!